# AS3 limit Area of zoom and swipe in Gesture script

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, gesture, flash-cs6

i want to simulate zoom ( magnifier ) some text info in my android app

use these script to enable swipe and Zoom Gesture to my text ( that i put in movieclip with instance name : textzoom)

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;  
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;  
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;  
import flash.events.GestureEvent;  
var origX:Number;  
var origY:Number;  

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;  


origX = textzoom.x;  
origY = textzoom.y;  
textzoom.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);  

function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {  


    if (textzoom.scaleX > 0.5 && textzoom.scaleX < 3) {  

        textzoom.scaleX *= e.scaleX;  
        textzoom.scaleY = textzoom.scaleX;  

    } else if (textzoom.scaleX < 0.5) {  
        textzoom.scaleX = 0.51;  
        textzoom.scaleY = textzoom.scaleX;  

    } else if (textzoom.scaleX > 3) {  
        textzoom.scaleX =2.99;  
        textzoom.scaleY = textzoom.scaleX;  
    }  

    //trace (e.scaleX );  
}  

stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe);  
function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{  


if (e.offsetX == 1) {  
//User swiped towards right  
textzoom.x += 100;  
}  
if (e.offsetX == -1) {  
//User swiped towards left  
textzoom.x -= 100;  
}  
if (e.offsetY == 1) {  
//User swiped towards bottom  
textzoom.y += 100;  
}  
if (e.offsetY == -1) {  
//User swiped towards top  
textzoom.y -= 100;  
}  
}   


Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;  
stage.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_TWO_FINGER_TAP, twoFingerTapHandler);  
function twoFingerTapHandler(event:GestureEvent):void  
{  
        textzoom.scaleX =1;  
        textzoom.scaleY = textzoom.scaleX;  
        textzoom.x = origX;  
        textzoom.y = origY;  

    }
```

now i can use zoom and swipe for read text in bigger size ( make easier to read ) , but now there is two problem :

1. when i zoom the text grows in stage and will cover all my screen and other part , and i don't want this , i just want the zoom function effect on the textzoom movieclip area .

2.the swipe function will continue till the text goes out of stage and disappeared !! how can i stop swipe function before textzoom movieclip goes out of stage completely ? so user can detect and see the corner of text and swipe them back

Comment: Wrap `textzoom` in a boxed sprite that'll have `clipRect` property set, and assign that listener to the wrapper.

Comment: thanks so much for reply , i get your tips in my mind but unfortantly i`m not pro in AS3 and cant find any Cliprect on google 

can you guide me more or get me some link that have tutorial or sample project like this 

thanks again

Comment: Sorry, there's no property `clipRect` indeed, I might be thinking about some other language where I've seen this. You need to set a mask for th parent sprite consisting of filled rectangle. Also, you can set `scrollRect` property for that parent, this way your text will also be scrollable.